# Can the baud rate corrupt an SD card?

Tags: android, sd-card, baud-rate

I'm working with a team of developers on an Android media player device. We're having a very bad time because the SD cards are keep getting corrupted and we don't have a clue why. At random times (but after a few days of r/w cycles on them) they can't be accessed anymore and we need to replace them.

I was reading an article about hardware bugs and this thing caught my attention:

(...)The clock lets the hardware device -- which isn't directly connected to the CPU -- stay in sync with the code the CPU is running. The clock determines the Baud Rate -- the rate at which data is sent from one side to the other. If the timing gets messed up, the hardware or the software -- or both -- get confused. This is really, really bad, and usually results in data corruption.

So I was thinking...could there be a possibility that the baud rate is related to our sd/usb cards corruption problem? Maybe there's a difference between the sd/usb card baud rate and the device's reader controller baud rate?

Something similar happened [here](http://letsmakerobots.com/strange-problem-when-saving-data-sd-card), although in a different project:

Quote: "However I cannot receive the file from the PC via the Xbee and write it to the SD card without loosing chunks for the file".

Full disclaimer: I'm not a developer but a BA. I have no idea if my question is a nonsense, I'm just trying to find an answer to our problem.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but is borderline off-topic for SO, and might be better asked at Android.SE or SuperUser.

Comment: How many r/w cycles are performed? Number of flash writes is very limited.

Comment: Not more than a few hundreds.